# Rails App/Bootstrap: How to Fix Dropdown Menu?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, ruby-on-rails-5

I am working through Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial (RoR 5) and am trying to create a dropdown menu as part of the web app.  I've followed Hartl's instructions carefully, but I cannot get the dropdown to actually appear on the page after logging in.

Past threads on Stack Overflow which discuss this same issue are 3+ years old, and as a result most of the gems (and corresponding solutions) referred to are outdated and don't seem to apply to recent versions of Rails (this tutorial uses version 5.1.2).

I have tried the following fixes (none have worked, and some cause errors):

- Including "require JQuery" and "require JQuery-ujs" in application.js
- Changing the listed order so that bootstrap loads before or after other components
- Using "require bootstrap-dropdown", which may be obsolete in newer bootstrap downloads
- Including $(document).dropdown methods in the coffee.js documents
- Restarting the web server various times

I am very much a beginner to Rails (and programming generally), so any advice you can offer is much appreciated.

Here are the documents which seem relevant/useful:

**GEMFILE**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.2'
#bcrypt for password hashing
gem 'bcrypt',         '3.1.11'
#Boostrap-Sass
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.7'

# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.13'
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'

end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '1.0.2'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.1.14'
  gem 'guard',                    '2.13.0'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.4'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.18.4'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

**app/javascripts/application.js:**

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

**_header.html.erb:**

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
        <% if logged_in? %>
          <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Account <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Settings", '#' %></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li>
                <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: :delete %>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

**apps/views/layouts/_rails_default.html.erb:**

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I did Michael's tutorial (July 2017) I ended up removing all the versions from the gem file.  This way rails just loads the latest version of each one.
So change:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.7'
```

to just:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

etc. for each gem in your gemfile.
I was getting all sorts of strange errors before I did this from different outdated and incompatible gems.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while working on RoR 6. After debugging a little, I found that the *logged_in?* helper function in the *_header* partial somehow outputs false even after logging in. I finally added the helper ***current_user*** before the *if* block.

```
<% current_user %>
<% if logged_in? %>
   .
   .
   .
<% end %>
```

which seems to be a workaround but solved it for me!